# p:selectOneRadio not updating model in event "change" with p:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, selectoneradio

I'm using an `p:selectOneRadio` with `p:ajax` and the value of another component (`p:inputText`), not binding its value in my bean.

If I use `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` instead the behavior is exactly what I need, update the bean before calling the method in ajax. Is this a bug in `p:selectOneRadio` or is this its default behavior?

I'm using *JSF2*, *PrimeFaces 4*

The **xhtml** code:

```
 <p:selectOneRadio id="enumId" value="#{xyzController.entity.enumValor}"
    disabled="#{disabled}" required="true" plain="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{xyzController.enum}" var="item"
        itemLabel="#{messages[ELUtils.evaluateExpression(itemLabelEL)]}"
        itemValue="#{item}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{xyzController.aoTrocar}"
        update="panelDominioFields" process="@form" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<p:outputPanel layout="inline" id="panelDominioFields">
    <p:inputText id="valorId"
        value="#{xyzController.entity.valorNumericoValido}"
        rendered="#{xyzController.mostrarCampoDominioNumerico}"
        required="true">
        <f:convertNumber type="number" locale="#{localeController.locale}"
            currencyCode="#{localeController.currencyCode}" />
    </p:inputText>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 6):

Get rid of `event="change"`, it's the wrong event. It defaults to `click` and is the right one already.

```
<p:ajax listener="#{xyzController.aoTrocar}"
    update="panelDominioFields" process="@form" />
```

Radio button values never change. They're only *selected* by click. In turn, selected values are submitted, but unselected values not.