# Hide and show components depending on h:selectOneRadio value

Tags: ajax, primefaces, selectoneradio

I have a page with a p:selectOneRadio and I want to show one datatable depending on the chosen value of the radio selection. I have the error:

> GRAVE: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException:  .......changeListenerMethod(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviourEvent)

My code is the following:

```
<p:selectOneRadio value="#{analysisOrderForm.selectedOrderDomain}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="choice1" itemValue="choice1"></f:selectItem>         
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="choice2" itemValue="choice2"></f:selectItem>
     <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{analysisOrderForm.changeListenerMethod}"/>
 </p:selectOneRadio>
 <h:PanelGroup>
    <p:dataTable rendered="#{analysisOrderForm.selectedOrderDomain == 'choice1'}">....</p:dataTable>
    <p:dataTable rendered="#{analysisOrderForm.selectedOrderDomain == 'choice2'}">....</p:dataTable>
 </h:PanelGroup>
```

The code of my 'changeListenerMethod method' is just:

```
 public void changeListenerMethod(ValueChangeEvent e){
      setSelectedOrderDomain(e.getValue().toString());
 }
```

What is correct and what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{analysisOrderForm.changeListenerMethod}"/>
```

JSF will look for a method in your `analysisOrderForm` bean which has the following signature: `public void changeListenerMethod(AjaxBehaviourEvent e)`. So you just need to replace `ValueChangeEvent` by `AjaxBehaviourEvent`.

---

**Notes:**

- Another alternative approach is to write a method that doesn't take any arguments such as `public void changeListenerMethod()` and references it in your listener with `listener="#{analysisOrderForm.changeListenerMethod()}`
- Event **change** is not the right event in your case. `p:selectOneRadio` event should be **click** (besides, that's the default event value). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21292158/2118909